# Perl array and hash manipulation using map

Tags: perl, arrays, sqlite, hash

I have the following test code

```
use Data::Dumper;

my $hash = {
            foo => 'bar',
            os  => 'linux'
           };

my @keys = qw (foo os);

my $extra = 'test';

my @final_array = (map {$hash->{$_}} @keys,$extra);

print Dumper \@final_array;
```

The output is

```
$VAR1 = [
          'bar',
          'linux',
          undef
        ];
```

Shouldn't the elements be "bar, linux, test"? Why is the last element undefined and how do I insert an element into @final_array? I know I can use the push function but is there a way to insert it on the same line as using the map command?

Basically the manipulated array is meant to be used in an SQL command in the actual script and I want to avoid using extra variables before that and instead do something like:

```
$sql->execute(map {$hash->{$_}} @keys,$extra);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$extra` is being passed through the `map` and since there's no entry in the hash with the key `test` the value is `undef`. Put parentheses around the `map` to force the parsing:

```
$sql->execute((map {$hash->{$_}} @keys),$extra);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also use a hash slice to avoid looping with map:

```
my @final_array = (@$hash{@keys}, $extra);
```